# import and clean text file in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have data in a text file in the following format.

(0.00, 1.00), (1.00, 0.93), (2.00, 0.86), (3.00, 0.8), (4.00, 0.75), (5.00, 0.7), (6.00, 0.65), (7.00, 0.6), (8.00, 0.56), (9.00, 0.52), (10.0, 0.49)

The first element within the parentheses is x and the second element is y. How do I create a matrix with the following format.

```
    x    y
    0    1
    1    0.93
    2    0.86
    3    0.8
    4    0.75
```

I have tried variants of read.table but with no success. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: depending on how close your actual data is to your example `matrix(scan(text = gsub('[() ]', '', text), sep = ','), ncol = 2L, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: Does it not have newlines? and doesn't have a header row? It is similar to a CSV (except possibly without newlines). So `gsub()` on the parentheses, and then `read.table(..., col.names=c('x','y'))`

Answer (score 1):

First we save your string as a file so solution is reproducible:

```
str0 <- "(0.00, 1.00), (1.00, 0.93), (2.00, 0.86), (3.00, 0.8), (4.00, 0.75), (5.00, 0.7), (6.00, 0.65), (7.00, 0.6), (8.00, 0.56), (9.00, 0.52), (10.0, 0.49)"
file1 <- "str1.xt"
write(str0,file1)
```

solution:

```
x <-  scan(file1, character())
x <-  as.numeric(gsub("[(,)]","",x))
x <-  matrix(x,ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE,dimnames = list(NULL,c("x","y")))
as.data.frame(x)
 # x    y
 # 1   0 1.00
 # 2   1 0.93
 # 3   2 0.86
 # 4   3 0.80
 # 5   4 0.75
 # 6   5 0.70
 # 7   6 0.65
 # 8   7 0.60
 # 9   8 0.56
 # 10  9 0.52
 # 11 10 0.49
```

alternate solution:

```
x <- gsub("), (",", ",scan(file1, character(),sep="_"),fixed = T)
as.data.frame(eval(parse(text=paste0("matrix(c",x,",ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE,dimnames = list(NULL,c('x','y')))"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
text <-
    "(0.00, 1.00), (1.00, 0.93), (2.00, 0.86), (3.00, 0.8), (4.00, 0.75), (5.00, 0.7), (6.00, 0.65), (7.00, 0.6), (8.00, 0.56), (9.00, 0.52), (10.0, 0.49)";

do.call(rbind, lapply(
    gsub("(\\s*\\(|\\)\\s*)", "", unlist(strsplit(text, split = "),"))),
    function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ", ")))))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0 1.00
# [2,]    1 0.93
# [3,]    2 0.86
# [4,]    3 0.80
# [5,]    4 0.75
# [6,]    5 0.70
# [7,]    6 0.65
# [8,]    7 0.60
# [9,]    8 0.56
#[10,]    9 0.52
#[11,]   10 0.49
```

Explanation: We first split entries on `"),"` to separate the rows, and after some cleaning separate entries on `", "` into column entries per row.

Or to avoid `do.call(rbind, ...)`

```
t(sapply(
    gsub("(\\s*\\(|\\)\\s*)", "", unlist(strsplit(text, split = "),"))),
    function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ", ")))))
#           [,1] [,2]
#0.00, 1.00    0 1.00
#1.00, 0.93    1 0.93
#2.00, 0.86    2 0.86
#3.00, 0.8     3 0.80
#4.00, 0.75    4 0.75
#5.00, 0.7     5 0.70
#6.00, 0.65    6 0.65
#7.00, 0.6     7 0.60
#8.00, 0.56    8 0.56
#9.00, 0.52    9 0.52
#10.0, 0.49   10 0.49
```